# A book about a girl who travels back to Medieval times?

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel

I need to find a book that I read in 2006. The plot I remember:

- The MC is a girl
- The landlord's son (or a prince) goes to the future. He met the girl and then they live together for 1-2 months.
- After that he comes back, 1-2 months later, the girl goes to the Middle Ages. She somehow met that guy and pretended to be an important person. She gets to eat off a silver plate (the best is gold).
- She knows that he still remembers about the future because he knows how to use the calculator she dropped
- ...( Middle of the book I don't remember)
- At the end she come back and visit the monument and see his statue there

Things I'm not sure of:

- The girl saves the mother of the landlord's son?
- He had a brother?

Comment: Well, I found the book [The Book of Time](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/221542) which has a calculator that travels through time but I don't think that's it :P

Comment: @Laurel I read those, and roughly nothing matches except the time travel part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly *[A Knight in Shining Armor](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Knight-Shining-Armor-Jude-Deveraux/dp/0743457269)* by Jude Deveraux, originally published in 1989.

I haven't read the book, but different reviews seem to match up with your synopsis.

Woman gets stranded in a Church in England, meets a Knight from the past next to his tomb.

She takes him in for a few months, he goes back to the past and a few months later she goes to the past too.

She comes back to the present after a few months and when she visits his tomb she can see that some things have changed about his history.

Some things that may jog your memory if this is the book you are looking for.

Her name is Dougless, his is Nicholas.

The book starts off with Dougless in an unhappy relationship with a man who has a rather bratty daughter.

In the present Nicholas is fascinated with books and book stores.

In the past he's a bit of a playboy and is not happy to see Dougless initially.

Comment: Many thanks. I read the book today and find out this is the one I am looking for.